# How to make transitions between images in canvas (unity)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

So I have 3 same images, but with different colors which I want to cycle in my menu. They are only with different hue/saturations and I want them to slowly reduce their alpha 1 by 1 so that the one behind pops up and then restart the cycle.

I'm trying to set a public image and reduce it's alpha, but it's not smooth.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Fading : MonoBehaviour {

    public Image image;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        //image.CrossFadeAlpha(50, 5, false);

        image.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer>().SetAlpha(0.1f);
        image.CrossFadeAlpha(10f, 4f, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should display the code you are using.

Comment: It just stays at the alpha stated. I added the code above. I was wondering if maybe somehow with with time.deltaTime, with a cycle I could reduce the alpha slightly with every second passed/substracted.

Comment: you just call `CrossFadeAlpha` ONCE from anywhere you want, it has no connection to `Update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CrossFadeAlpha](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic.CrossFadeAlpha.html) should only be called to start the image fade transition, via a button press or similar, as the method works similar to a [Coroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html), example (on mouse button press);

```
public class ImageFade : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Image m_img;
    [SerializeField]
    private float m_fadeDuration;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool m_ignoreTimeScale;

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            m_img.CrossFadeAlpha(0f, m_fadeDuration, m_ignoreTimeScale);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
            m_img.CrossFadeAlpha(1f, m_fadeDuration, m_ignoreTimeScale);
    }
}
```

However if you would prefer to control this functionality manually, you have to take a longer approach. Below you can see that every time the mouse is pressed, the fade multiplier is negated, making it always 1 or -1. This value is then multiplied by the fraction of time needed for this update (before being added to the current alpha value);

```
Time.deltaTime / m_fadeDuration
```

As well as this, the boolean m_requiresUpdate, makes sure to avoid unnecessary updates, setting itself to false after the fade is complete.

```
public class ImageFade : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Image   m_img;
    [SerializeField]
    private float   m_fadeDuration;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool    m_ignoreTimeScale;

    private int     m_fadeMultiplier;
    private float   m_alpha;
    private bool    m_requiresUpdate;

    public void Start()
    {
        m_fadeMultiplier    = 1;
        m_alpha             = 1f;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        //Toggle subtracting/adding
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            m_fadeMultiplier = -m_fadeMultiplier;
            m_requiresUpdate = true;
        }

        //Update
        if (m_requiresUpdate)
        {
            //Fade
            m_alpha = Mathf.Clamp(m_alpha + (m_fadeMultiplier * (Time.deltaTime / m_fadeDuration)), 0f, 1f);
            m_img.canvasRenderer.SetAlpha(m_alpha);

            //Finished fading
            if (m_alpha == 0f || m_alpha == 1f)
                m_requiresUpdate = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this ties everything together nicely for you.